# CALayerInvalidGeometry when going from one view to another

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

After editing a value in one view and then going to another view (with a custom button and navigationlink) I get the following Error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan nan].
```

Code from my custom button is:

```
                    NavigationLink(destination: TripNotesEvalView(currentTrip: self.currentTrip), isActive: self.$goToNextView, label: { EmptyView() })
                        ZStack {
                            Image("btn-shape").resizable().frame(width: 60, height: 70).colorMultiply(self.btnThreeData.color)
                        }.onTapGesture {
                            self.goToNextView = true
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that a custom button doesn't closes the keyboard which was causing the problem after closing the keyboard before setting the next view boolean to true the problem was solved:

to close the keyboard:

```
extension UIApplication {
    func endEditing() {
        sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
```

implemented this method in my navigation button just before i set the boolean to true:

```
NavigationLink(destination: TripNotesEvalView(currentTrip: self.currentTrip), isActive: self.$goToNextView, label: { EmptyView() })
ZStack {
    Image("btn-shape").resizable().frame(width: 60, height: 70).colorMultiply(self.btnThreeData.color)
}.onTapGesture {
    UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
    self.goToNextView = true
}
```

This solved the problem for me!